# Animating and removing an NSImageView object failed?

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation, core-animation, catransaction

**My app situation:**
I am now having an app displaying a dynamic picture. And I want to capture its current image and save it to disc.

**My goal:**
I am working on an animated visual effect: add an image view on top, and then animates it from its origin frame into CGRecrZero. Finally, remove this image view from vie hierarchy after animation is done.

---

**Now problem:**
First time triggerring the action, it seems work. But when trigger it at the second time, the image view does not animate and stay atop of all subviews.

---

**Codes of the view controller**(with ARC):

Firstly, this is the IBAction to trigger the snapshot:

```
- (IBAction)actionSaveSnapshot:(id)sender
{
    ...    // Save the image file. This works everytime.

    NSThread *tempThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                   selector:@selector(threadSimulateScreenCapture:) 
                                                     object:nil];
    if (tempThread)
    {
        [tempThread start];
        tempThread = nil;     // Simply release it 
    }
}
```

And here is the thread:

```
- (void)threadSimulateScreenCapture:(id)arg
{@autoreleasepool {
    NSImageView __strong *subImageView;
    subImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    NSRect subRect = [_imageView frame];    // the dynamic image view which I want to snapshot with
    const CGFloat animationTime = 0.4;

    [subImageView setWantsLayer:YES];
    [subImageView setImageScaling:NSImageScaleAxesIndependently];
    [subImageView setImage:[_imageView image]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [CATransaction begin];
        [self.view addSubview:subImageView];
        [subImageView setFrame:subRect];
        [subImageView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        [CATransaction commit];
    });

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:animationTime];
        [subImageView.layer setFrame:CGRectZero];
        [CATransaction commit];
    });

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)animationTime];    // wait for end of animation

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [subImageView removeFromSuperview];
    });

    NSLog(@"SubView Count: %@\n%@", self.view.subviews, subImageView);  // MARK. described below
    subImageView = nil;    // release the image
}} // ENDS: thread and aotureleasepool
```

Every time the program runs to the "MARK" line and print the subview array, it is clear thar the `subImageView` is not removed from superview then. And every time the thread ends, a "deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction ...." raised.

What wrong did I do?

Answer (score 0):

I may solved my own problem: At the line with `[subImageView setFrame:subRect];`, insert another line with: `[subImageView.layer setFrame:subRect];`

Meanwhile, add another line before the "addSubview:" method: `[self.view setWantsLayer:YES];`.

It seemed work. But I do not know why. Why I should set both view and layer's frame?